# Unable to download a package via cargo -- timeout

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I generally have no issues with cargo but with this one package:

```
$ cargo build --verbose
 Downloading hyper v0.9.1
unable to get packages from source

Caused by:
  failed to download package `hyper v0.9.1` from https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/hyper/0.9.1/download

Caused by:
  Timeout was reached
```

Hyper v0.9.1 does exist. I see the same issue with 0.8 which also exists.

Comment: Have you attempted to ping `crates.io`, and if so what was the result?

Comment: I was able to download that crate via cargo just now. Chances are there was some transient failure in the network. If this still occurs, try downloading that url (`https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/hyper/0.9.1/download`) directly.